# Angular 4 ngOnInit not working when loading the component first time

Tags: javascript, angular

I Have a component in Angular 4 that and a template to change the route 
This component is called but does not load anything no server call.
If i put the ngOnInit() method content into constructor it works fine.
It seems ngOnInit is not called. Anybody please can help i am working on this since last 2 days.

here is my routing configuration.

```
const testRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
        { path:'createtest/:id', component:TestComponent, resolve: { test:TestResolver }},
        { path:'createtest', component:TestComponent, resolve: { test:TestResolver }},
        { path:'testlist', component:TestListComponent }
]);


import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {TestService,Test} from '../shared'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
    selector:'test-list',
    templateUrl:'./testlist.component.html'
})
export class TestListComponent implements OnInit{
    testList:Array<Test>;
    constructor(private testService:TestService){}
    ngOnInit = ()=>{
        this.testService.getTest()
        .subscribe(
            data=>this.testList = <Array<Test>>data,
            error=>alert(error)
        );
        console.log("ngOnInit");
    }
}
```

And here is my template to configure routing

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">SLearn</a>
    <a class="xyz" routerLink="/testlist">Test List</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: is there any reason you're using `ngOnInit = ()=>{...}` over `ngOnInit() {...}`?

Comment: not any specific reason but what is the difference between arrow and simple function

Comment: that's a separate question, but the gist of it is that the former creates `ngOnInit` property on the instance, while the latter on the prototype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to `overload` the `ngOnInit` function. This doesn't work with arrow functions.

You have to do:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.getTest()
    .subscribe(
        data=>this.testList = <Array<Test>>data,
        error=>alert(error)
    );
    console.log("ngOnInit");
}
```

Hope i could help.

---

### Update (Additional information thanks to maximus):

While a normal function declaration creates the `ngOnInit` property on the prototype, an arrow function creates it on the instance.

Angular itself  [looks only for the hooks on the prototype.](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities.ts#L205) which is why your original approach doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Actually, no. It's just not intended. Overloading functions have to follow a specific signature. with an arrow function the context is not the same as using a normal function declaration. I found only one article mentioning this, but why exactly, i cant tell you: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/11/01/overloading-typescript-functions.aspx

Comment: It doesn't work with arrow functions because you are not actually overloading when you do it that way: you're creating a variable called `ngOnInit` that exists in the class' scope and then assigning a function to it, rather than telling the class you are implementing a super class method.

Comment: True, the syntax is valid and the function is usable, but the question was why :P With a normal function declaration your are also creating a "variable" called `ngOnInit` that exists in the class scope or are you not?

Comment: Go to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ and choose "Using Inheritance", change *class Horse'* implementation of `move() {}` to `move = () =>` and see how the JavaScript emitted differs for that class.

Comment: it's because angular compiler [searches prototype for hooks](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/reflection/reflection_capabilities.ts#L205), and not instance [while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827678/angular-4-ngoninit-not-working-when-loading-the-component-first-time#comment76636037_44827678)... You can add this information to your answer